# Decorate ES6 class method without using @ syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Normally you decorate a function using the syntax:

```
@decorate
function x() {
  console.log('wow am I decorated')
}
```

However flow doesn't yet support this syntax. An easy workaround is that you can do

```
const x = decorate(function() {
  console.log('wow am I decorated')
})
```

But how can I achieve the same result inside of a class?

```
class plsWork {
  how2decorate() {
    console.log('why can I not be decorated :sob:')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends. Since you don't adhere to the current standard you could use class properties:

```
class plsWork {
  how2decorate = decorate(function() {
    console.log('why can I not be decorated :sob:')
  })
}
```

Another way is to add the method in the constructor, which is what a transpiler does with the first solution anyway:

```
class plsWork {
  constructor() {
    this.how2decorate = decorate(() => {
      console.log('why can I not be decorated :sob:')
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! And thanks for actually reading the question before posting haha.

Comment: @AR7 You can also say `plsWork.how2decorate = decorate(plsWork.how2decorate)` right after class definition. That should work for static methods too.

Comment: @Nikita Why would you add a property to a function?

Comment: @zeroflagL That's not what I'm doing. I'm updating an *existing* property on a *class*, wrapping it into a decorator. It's pretty much just desugaring of the ES6 `@decorate` syntax.

Comment: @Nikita `plsWork.how2decorate = ` adds the property `how2decorate` to the function ´plsWork`. `class plsWork {  how2decorate` is the same as `plsWork.prototype.how2decorate`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to do anything fancy. Method decorators are supported via the `.flowconfig` option `esproposal.decorators=ignore`.

Support for class decorators have just been [pulled in today](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/1638) and should make it into the next release.

Comment: Oh wow good to know! The .flowconfig options wasn't working for me earlier, but the new support sounds promising